# Recite Sura Yaseen in my prayer

Tags: salat

Assalamualaykum, Since Sura Yaseen is too long, how many verses can I recite in my prayer after Sura Fatiha?

Comment: Considering it too long is your subjective impression the sahabah used to recite surat Yusuf in one raka'a the prophet even recited many long surahs in one.

Answer (score 1):

Walikum Us Salam.
At least 3 verse if it is short & one verse if that is long.
In case of Surah Yaseen at least 3 verse is mandatory to recite after Surah Fatiha.Then u can longer as ur comfort.

Answer (score 1):

وعليكم السلام ورحمة الله وبركاته,

Technically you could say all of Surah Yāsīn, but the minimum is three small verses, or one long verse equivalent to that.

Further information: https://islamqa.org/hanafi/darulifta-deoband/27807